# Is it possible to look up an eks cluster without knowing the region?

Tags: amazon-eks

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this with aws cli, but I'm open to alternatives. Assuming I'm authenticated to a particular aws account, is there any way to look up basic information about a cluster, or all clusters in the account, without knowing what region the cluster is in? I'd love a way to get information about a cluster without already knowing meta information about it. I could write a script to cycle through all regions looking for for clusters, but I hope there's a better way.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to look up the region a cluster is in?

Answer (score 4):

A handy command is `eksctl get cluster --all-regions -o json`.

Comment: it's `--all-regions` with an s at the end

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash for loop that should do the trick:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f4`
do
     echo -e "\nListing Clusters in region: $region..."
     aws eks list-clusters --region $region --output text --no-cli-pager
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this project [`kdiscover`](https://github.com/mateimicu/kdiscover) for this.

You can install it as a binary and run `kdiscover aws list` to list all clusters.

Or you can install it using [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew) by runing:

1. `kubectl krew install discover`
2. then `kubectl discover aws list` to list all clusters.

You can also use `kdiscover aws update` or `kubectl discover aws update` to export/update all the kubeconfig info.